# One person intermittently muted during Zoom but not in recording

Tags: audio, windows-11, zoom-meeting

In zoom calls I have one person who is constantly difficult to hear. They are constantly cutting in and out (more out than in). No one else on the calls experiences this issue except for me.

This happens regardless of the audio output I'm using (speakers, headphones, etc).

This happens regardless of where I am (i.e. in the office, at home) nor does the number of participants impact it (1:1's are plagued by the problem same as 20 person calls).

What is extremely odd is that if I record the session using Windows Game Bar, then the audio comes through perfectly clear in the recording.

I'm wondering if this could be some sort of audio-processing that my computer is doing, but I haven't the foggiest clue as to where to start. I don't believe it's Zoom since the audio is perfectly fine in recordings.

Comment: If the recording is fine then the audio is coming through properly. 

The problem might actually be your own ambient microphone noise fooling Zoom into thinking you are trying to talk over them and thus effectively muting them for you.

As a test it might be worth muting yourself or lowering your microphone gain slightly.

Comment: I stay muted 95% of the time. And have used different input/output methods (webcam for mic, headphones for mic, laptop for mic, laptop for speakers, 3 different headphones , etc)

Comment: Can you try the following? Press **Win +r** to bring up a run window and enter `control mmsys.cpl sounds` which should bring up an old-style control panel window. On the **Communications** tab change the setting to **Do nothing** then click Apply/OK. It does sound like something weird is going on.

Comment: @Mokubai I'll give it a shot